# Urls laravel con alias

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

tengo la siguiente url

```
Route::get('faq', 'HomeController@faq');
```

http://www.dominio.com/faq

Quiero agregar un alias a esa url de forma que al ingresar me quede asi

http://www.dominio.com/preguntas-frecuentes

pero haciendo refenrecia a la url "faq" no se si desde el .htaccess se pueda

Comment: ¿No sera mejor que coloques todas las rutas en 'routes.php' o los ficheros en que lo tengas dividido y no empieces a poner algunas en el *.htaccess*?, por no complicar el mantenimiento futuro digo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Laravel 5.1 era así:

```
Route::get( 'faq' , 'HomeController@faq' );
Route::get( 'preguntas-frecuentes', [ 'as' => 'faq', 'uses' => 'HomeController@faq' ]);
```

Comment: y en caso de que la ruta sea un Route::resource o un Route::controller seria igual ?

Comment: Eso no lo he trabajado, tendras que hacer pruebas. Lo he visto en la documentación de Laravel 5.5: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers